# How to troubleshoot SymbolSource Server Basic

Tags: nuget-package, debug-symbols, nuget-server, symbol-server

I have [SymbolSource Server Basic](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/2012-03-13/Releasing_the_community_edition_of_SymbolSource) installed and running, following the instructions in [this blog entry](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/setting-up-your-own-symbolsource-server-step-by-step).

I can successfully push packages (*.nupkg and *.symbols.nupkg) from TeamCity to my server with no errors. However, while the NuGet side works well in Visual Studio, the Symbol Server is not working. I found that my local website's Data folder contains the standard NuGet packages I pushed, but there is no sign of any of my source code.

Where should I look for error messages, or how else can I tell why my *.symbols.nupkg does not appear to have been pushed correctly to the server?

Comment: Any success on this issue?

Comment: Sorry, Alex. Nothing to report. I changed to using NuPeek, and wrote it up here: http://www.geekzone.co.nz/dmw/8356